# How does the new money system work in Counter-Strike Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was recently watching CSGO, and noticed that the win/lose rewards were changed from a few months ago, as teams were buying earlier than I thought was possible.

How does the new money system in CSGO work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new money system was added on October 9th, 2018.

There was only really one change to the money system, and the intention was to change the behaviour in rounds following the loss of a first round (pistol round).

The extent of the change, as taken from the [official Counter-Strike Blog](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2018/10/21333/) is:

> "Adjusted the start-of-half economy with the goal of reducing the impact of a pistol round win on subsequent rounds."
>
> "— In Competitive Matchmaking, both teams are now considered to start the half with a one-round ‘losing streak’ that is reset following a round win. Instead of $1400, the Round 1 loser receives $1900, then $2400 for a subsequent loss, etc."

Basically, this change reduces the huge impact that the pistol round (first round) had on the outcome of the following rounds, and therefore the match itself.